# Temporal Clause for Past Participle

Tags: gerunds, past-participles, adverbials

I was wondering if there is a difference between reduced temporal clause with gerund and reduced temporal clause with past participle, and which one is used in formal setting?

For example: 
Sentence A: The plant dies after being exposed to hazardous chemicals.
Sentence B: The plant dies after exposed to hazardous chemicals.

I am always inclined to use sentence A since I never heard of the reduction of clause like in B.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which noun is the object of the preposition *after* in your case B?

Comment: I confess not to know anything about temporal clauses, but as a native speaker sentence A sounds infinitely preferable. I think I have somewhere or other heard the B format used. But I don't like it at all. If you wanted to shorten the sentence, why not say *...after exposure to hazardous chemicals*. Can a noun (gerund?) be created from a past participle?

Comment: @WS2 The only thing close to case B occurs in the peculiar dialect of Western Pennsylvania, where *Your face needs washed* (in?)famously occurs, despite that construction being ungrammatical for native speakers elsewhere.

Comment: @tchrist In Britain we are not short of regional expressions which would not pass grammatical muster in the Queen's English. But I am just trying to think of one of our dialects which might say *your face needs washed*. I think I have heard it somewhere.

Comment: @WS2: Indeed. According to Grammar Girl, "The 'needs washed' construction is common in Scotland and Northern Ireland according to both linguists and a few Scottish and Irish respondents to my question" [[link](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/needs-washed?page=1)].

Comment: @ruakh Yes I was going to suggest Ireland. Where did the inhabitants of Western Pennsylvania come from? Was there Irish settlement there?

Comment: @WS2: According to the *rest* of the sentence I quoted from, "when southwestern Pennsylvania was first settled by Europeans in the late 1600s and early 1700s, most of the settlers were Scots-Irish, a group of people with Scottish heritage who had settled for a few generations in the Ulster region of Northern Ireland". \[[link](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/needs-washed?page=1)] So -- yes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The unreduced form of the temporal clause is "The plant dies after it is exposed."  Your example A is the reduced form: "The plant dies after being exposed."  Your example B is ungrammatical.  I don't see any difference in meaning or in formality between the unreduced and reduced forms.

Comment: Thank you. I was having second thought on this problem, since my friend, who is a native speaker, said that the example B is common use. But now everything's cleared up. Thanks again!